# Новый хороший текст для «образцового резюме» участника

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

Есть такой текст. Он показывается пользователю [при заполнении информации на странице пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current), когда поле «о себе» пусто.

> BY DAY: Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl at Veridian Dynamics.
>
> BY NIGHT: I write code and code rights for penalcoders.example.org, an awesome non-profit that will totally take your money at that link. My kids are cuter than yours.
>
> FOR FUN: C+ Jokes, Segway Roller Derby, NYT Sat. Crosswords (in Sharpie!), Ostrich Grooming.
>
> "If you see scary things, look for the helpers-you'll always see people helping."-Fred Rogers

Насколько я понимаю, это своеобразная пародия на строгие официальные резюме, которая призывает рассказать о себе что-нибудь интересное, касающееся вашей работы и других хобби, но при этом не заморачиваться серьёзностью изложения.

Когда-то у этого резюме был дословный перевод, но он слетел. Мне он не нравился, потому что шутки про ниндзя-ковбоек не очень вписываются в нашу культуру и менталитет. Чем восстанавливать его, предлагаю написать новый — хороший, оригинальный и душевный.

Предлагайте варианты в ответах!

(Только, пожалуйста, помните, что Ru.SO пользуются разработчики из разных стран.)

Когда появятся конкурирующие варианты, я собираюсь пришпилить этот вопрос меткой [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5), чтобы как можно больше участников оценили ваш труд и оставили замечания и предложения.

[Tx:6861](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/51270940?key=58d989d1e7c9c04a6a03d55bbaa60470)

Comment: Тут почти каждое слово или словосочетание имеет свои непростые корни. Может для начала соберем откуда что взялось и какие аналоги можно придумать?

Comment: @tutankhamun отличная идея, поддерживаю.

Comment: Поскольку поле ввода описания отображает "заглушку" моноширинным шрифтом, есть смысл оформить оригинал и предлагаемые варианты так же.

Comment: @D-side не возражаю, редактируйте. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin ссылка **править** на Мете у меня неактивна, я бы и рад .-.

Comment: @D-side: поправил. Кстати, вроде бы теперь ссылка должна быть вам доступна.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Разберем исходник.

**Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl** - видимо, отсылка к популярным баззвордам из вакансий: Ninja, Cowboy, Rockstar. Еще мерещится аллюзия на <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>
**Veridian Dynamics** - вымышленная компания из сериала Везунчик Тед (Better Off Ted). Сферическая корпорация в вакууме.
**penalcoders** - программисты-уголовники, скамеры.
**My kids are cuter than yours** - своего рода мем/явление в американской родительской среде. Сравните с нашими *пузожителями*.
**C+ Jokes** - шутки "на троечку", посредственный юмор.
**Segway Roller Derby** - [роллер-дерби](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8) - популярный, преимущественно женский вид спорта (судя по cowgirl в начале - это женская анкета). Segway вместо роликовых коньков добавлен для нагнетания абсурда.
**NYT Sat. Crosswords** - субботние кроссворды в New York Times. **Sharpie** -  производитель фломастеров. Похоже, наша героиня любит риск.
**Ostrich Grooming** - уход за страусами. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

В конце цитата про то, что не надо бояться искать помощи. Люди любят совать цитаты в профили.

Попробуем набросать черновик, адаптированный к русскоязычной среде.

---

> Обо мне:
>
> **Днем** работаю тыжпрограммистом в ООО «Рога и Копыта».
>
> **По ночам** пишу код для своего инновационного стартапа [http://кулхацкер.example.org](http://%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80.example.org). Мои дети прочитали «Энциклопедию профессора Фортрана». У моей собаки есть ЖЖ, а на гитхабе у неё больше друзей, чем у меня.
>
> **Хобби:** коллекционирую смешные картинки из интернета, решаю судоку перманентным маркером, учу медведя кататься на велосипеде.
>
> *«Главная проблема цитат в интернете в том, что люди сразу верят в их подлинность»* — В.И. Ленин

Comment: Для обсуждения этого варианта, мнений, предложений, шуток и благодарностей создан [специальный чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35232/discussion-on-answer-by-nofate-------).

Comment: Ого, звёздный ответ получился ))

Comment: "на гитхабе больше друзей, чем у меня" — вот здесь что-то не очень. "На гитхабе" — это всё равно "у меня". Не знаю, как сформулировать лаконично, но за основу можно взять, "на гитхабе больше друзей, чем в реальной жизни", "у моего профиля гитхаба больше друзей, чем у меня" и т. п.

Comment: @Discord, у собаки больше друзей, чем у меня. В том предложении речь про собаку )

Comment: @Nofate Тогда я вообще ничего не понял. Можно полное предложение совсем без опущенных слов?

Comment: @Discord, *У моей собаки есть ЖЖ, и на гитхабе [у неё] больше друзей, чем у меня.*

Comment: @Nofate Почему рассказывается про ЖЖ, а друзья считаются на гитхабе?

Comment: @Discord, собака всесторонне развита.

Comment: @Nofate В таком случае разумно использовать союз "а" вместо "и", и не выбрасывать "у неё" — это экономия на спичках.

Comment: @Discord, совершенно не возражаю.

Comment: @Nofate У нас "е" или "ё" принято использовать?

Comment: @Discord: принято «ё».

Comment: Я применил ваш ответ с незначительными правками пунктуации.

Comment: Кстати. У нас ведь не говорят «днём/по ночам». У нас сказали бы «**Работаю** тыжпрограмистом, **вне работы** / **после работы** / **хобби** / **увлекаюсь** ...».

Comment: хм... ну я говорю **по ночам**. хотя я могу быть и нерепрезентативным.

Answer (score 2):

**Глоссарий оригинального текста**
**Alt-Rock** - Alternative rock, кнопка Alt на клавиатуре
**Veridian Dynamics** - корпорация зла, Google, Microsoft etc
**code rights** - The Code of Rights - что-то про какой-то закон Новой Зелландии
**penalcoders** - Penal Code - уголовное законодательство
**С+** - шутки "на троечку", аллюзия к С++
**Segway Roller Derby** - гонки на велосипедах
**NYT Sat. Сrosswords** - кроссворды из Комсомолки-толстушки
**Sharpie** - <del>напоминает</del> аллюзия к С-Sharp
**Ostrich** - <del>от русского слова</del> возможно имеет общие корни с русским словом Остричь
**scary things** - "обратная" аллюзия к блогу Coding Horror

Comment: Ostrich – это [страус и не только](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=ostrich&l1=1). Segway – это далеко не велосипед, он сам по себе едет тихонько и гонки на них должны быть довольно унылым занятием.

Comment: "NYT Sat. Crosswords" – возможно, кроссворды в субботнем выпуске New York Times. Ещё [SAT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT) – это что-то вроде ЕГЭ.

Comment: `NYT Sat. Сrosswords` - это субботные кроссворды в газете New York Times. Самые простые - в понедельник, а самые сложные - в субботу. `Sharpie - напоминает С#` Sharpie - это имя бренда перманентного маркера. `Ostrich - от русского слова Остричь` Хаха, нет, американских программистов, которые знают русское слово "остричь", почти нету.  Даже я не знал. Ostrich - это страус, птица известна своей уродливостью.